# Compliler gives error in nonsense function

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I am using the Codeblock IDE with MingW, I have an ongoing problem
with the following types of errors. (File || Message)

```
obj\CEntity.o(.text+0x71a) || In function `ZN7CEntity6OnMoveEff':
```

OR

```
obj\CArea.o(.bss+0x0) || In function `ZNSt6vectorI5CTileSaIS0_EEaSERKS2_':
obj\CApp_OnCleanup.o(.bss+0x0):C:\DevCpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\vector.tcc || first defined here
```

Note that it gives the location as some sort of obj file so I cannot
see where it is in my code.

My C++ is improving a lot but I am still not very good understanding 
how the compilers work and I cannot figure out what might be causing
the problem or how to go about solving issues like this. Unlike a code
problem it is really hard to google because the names have just been
scrambled.

Hopefully someone can help because it is holding me back and I just cannot find 
or figure out a fix!

(I decided not to post my code because it is many interlinked files and I do not 
know where the error is but I am trying to follow the tutorials on http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics. The first few I can get to work
but then the later ones always seem to fail. It is obviously something I am doing wrong
because when I use the sample it works.)

Comment: It's called name mangling. Don't worry about it, look at the actual error messages, not their context. (BTW, those are linker errors, not compiler errors.)

Comment: It looks as if the MinGW you're using - or at least the stl files that it's looking at - is pretty old (3.4.2 from 2004 it seems). A leftover from an old DevCpp installation maybe? If you've installed the CodeBlocks version that comes with its own MinGW, try cleaning up your path variables to make sure there aren't any leftovers from your DevCpp MinGW. Or just uninstall both DevCpp and CodeBlocks and reinstall CodeBlocks with MinGW...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many GCC distributions (such as the MinGW distros I use) come with a utility names `c++filt` which will turn a C++ mangled name into something closer to the source code declaration (I think your error messages left out some underscores):

```
C:\temp>c++filt __ZN7CEntity6OnMoveEff
CEntity::OnMove(float, float)
```

MSVC comes with a similar utility: `undname`

However, you may want to update the MinGW you're using. I get nice, demangled names directly in the error output going back to MinGW 3.4.5 (similarly for MSVC going back to VC++6):

```
class CEntity {
    public:
        void OnMove(float, float);
};

int main()
{
    CEntity ent;
    ent.OnMove(1., 2.);
}
```

Compiled with MinGW 3.4.5:

```
C:\temp>g++ -o test.exe test.cpp
C:\...\ccwlXEih.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `CEntity::OnMove(float, float)'
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had downloaded the latest one but I will try and update by MinGW now!